# Don't use a reference's id when creating an object

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two objects in my app: `user` which has a unique parameter `email_address` and `node` which has a name and belongs to a user.

Here is my two objects in the DB, Node:

```
class CreateNodes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :nodes do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.references :user, index: true, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

And User:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :email_address, unique: true, index: true

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

My form to add a node looks like this:

```
<%= form_for @node do |f|  %>
    <%= f.text_field :name, :class => "form-control" %>
    <%= f.number_field :user_id, :class => "form-control" %>
    <%= f.submit 'Add the node' %>
<% end %>
```

However, I would like to use the user's `email_address` parameter instead of his/her id for convenience. I already did the changes in my controller to find the id linked to the email address but my new form returns an error, here it is:

```
<%= form_for @node do |f|  %>
    <%= f.text_field :name, :class => "form-control" %>
    <%= f.email_field :user_email_address, :class => "form-control" %>
    <%= f.submit 'Add the node' %>
<% end %>
```

The error:

```
undefined method `user_email_address' for #<Node id: nil, name: nil, user_id: nil>
```

The problem returned is clear but I don't know how to add this method and still follow the best practices for RoR development, any suggestions?

Comment: paste your associations

Comment: Post the `Node` and `User` class code as well. If possible, then attributes/columns you have in users table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have the below line :

```
<%= f.email_field :user_email_address, :class => "form-control" %>
```

The `f` object, which is a `Node` object, calling the method `user_email_address` on itself. As there is no such method, you are getting the error.

Add a method inside the `Node` model:

```
def user_email_address
  self.user.email_address
end
```

After adding the above method, below will work :

```
<%= f.email_field :user_email_address, :class => "form-control" %>
```

Comment: Looks correct! It returns an error when I'm reaching node/new because the node doesn't exist yet but I just need to add code in the method to handle the case.